# Returning dynamically generated module from a method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a bunch of classes with similiar logic like this

```
class ApiWrapper
  class << self
    attr_accessor :app_id, :app_key

    def configure
      yield self
    end
  end
end
```

I want to extract this logic to a module similar to Ruby Struct class to be able to do something like this

```
class ApiWrapper
  include Configurable.instance :app_id, :app_key
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-c-new)

```
fred = Module.new do
  def meth1
    "hello"
  end
  def meth2
    "bye"
  end
end
```